# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1) for image opening

Tags: python, numpy

I want to open the file for image processing, but I am facing problems

My code is-

```
 import numpy as np
 import cv2
 from scipy import ndimage
 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
 from PIL import Image,ImageOps
 from skimage import color,measure,io
 img=cv2.imread('trail_image.tif')
 img1=np.array(img, dtype=np.float)
 b,g,r =cv2.split(img1)
 rgb_img1 =cv2.merge([r,g,b])
 gray = cv2.cvtColor(img1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
 pixels_to_um =0.253
 kernel = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)
 opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel, iterations = 2)
 closing = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel, iterations = 2)
 sure_bg = cv2.dilate(closing,kernel,iterations=3)
 sure_bg = cv2.dilate(closing,kernel,iterations=3)
 dist_transform = cv2.distanceTransform(sure_bg,cv2.DIST_L2,3)
 ret, sure_fg = cv2.threshold(dist_transform,0.1*dist_transform.max(),255,0)
 plt.subplot(321),plt.imshow(rgb_img1)
 plt.title('Input Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
 plt.subplot(322),plt.imshow(thresh, 'gray')
 plt.title("Otsu's binary threshold"), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
 plt.subplot(323),plt.imshow(closing, 'gray')
 plt.title("morphologyEx:Closing:2x2"), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
 plt.subplot(324),plt.imshow(sure_bg, 'gray')
 plt.title("Dilation"), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
 plt.subplot(325),plt.imshow(dist_transform, 'gray')
 plt.title("Distance Transform"), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([]) 
 plt.subplot(326),plt.imshow(sure_fg, 'gray')
 plt.title("Thresholding"), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
 plt.tight_layout()
 plt.show()
```

Comment: Please read [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you improve the level of detail in your question. "I'm facing problems" isn't very helpful to people who would like to help you. You do mention the error message in the title, but you haven't included the Traceback so that we can see exactly where the error has occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing your error with a sample `tiff` image. The error is in the line 
`b,g,r =cv2.split(img1)`.
I have a hunch that you are not using the correct extension while loading the image -
`img=cv2.imread('trail_image.tif')` here.  Try using `img=cv2.imread('trail_image.tiff')` instead and it might work.

When I loaded `img=cv2.imread('trail_image.tif')` it didn't throw an error but assigned a `None` value to `img`, which is why you were getting the error that you got. In order for `b,g,r = cv2.split(img1)` to work, `img1` has to be a 3 channel RGB image, but since `img1` got assigned to `None`, `cv2.split()` did not get a 3D array to split.

In future, to debug such problems you should always check if your image is loading correctly.